# ASP/.NET web sites to inactivate after a certain time of inactivity

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

I am using shared hosting for my website which is build on ASP.NET web-form and hosted on IIS server. The purpose of this website is only for reset password and admin panel changes for a IOS application. Now we are facing an issue that reset password link sent to user on email takes 2-3 minutes sometime when user click on it. We raised the same to our hosting provider and get this answer:

> it is standard in ASP/.NET web sites to inactivate the application
>   pool (where the code is run) after a certain time of inactivity (180
>   min) which means that the next visit requires the code the be compiled
>   to memory from scratch every time the application is started by the
>   web server.

I need help to setup how can we make the website to up and live and not to compile code from scratch. Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Find a spare machine and run a script (in PowerShell maybe) there to access your site every 175 minutes.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your suggestion but how will I call the site after 175 minutes regularly? I am thinking to create a window scheduler on my local machine to do this job, but what kind of code I have to put into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can create windows service or schedule task to run an app to call your server, but the easiest way to solve this would be to set up one of the free site monitoring services like [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/). It will ping your site every 5 minutes or as often as it will be configured and keep it up and running. Bonus status updates if your site goes down.